# Spring Hibernate PrimeFaces error with PostgreSQL schema url

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have some problem about connecting postgresql database with spring bean, 
the database url is `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Misure`, in this there are many schema, and in the schema `monitoraggio` there are many table, I want the table `clienti`

**This is my code:**

```
application-context.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <!-- Enable Spring Annotation Configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scan for all of Spring components such as Spring Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="spring.service"></context:component-scan>
    <!-- Create Data Source bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Misure" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="Fabio1990"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- Define SessionFactory bean -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Cliente.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Detect @Transactional Annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

**This is `hibernate.cfg.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**This is `cliente.hbm.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="data.Cliente" table="clienti">
    <id column="id" name="clienteId" type="java.lang.Long">
      <generator class="identity">
        <param name="identity">clienti_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property column="nome" name="clienteNome" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property column="cognome" name="clienteCognome" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property column="telefono" name="clienteTelefono" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property column="mail" name="clienteMail" type="string">            
 </property>
    <property column="permesso" name="clientePermesso" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property column="commessa" name="clienteCommessa" type="string">            
</property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**This is `registerCliente.java`:**

```
package beans;


import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import data.Cliente;
import spring.service.ClienteService;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class RegisterCliente {

    @ManagedProperty("#{clienteService}")
    private ClienteService clienteService;

    private Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

    public ClienteService getClienteService() {
        return clienteService;
    }

    public void setClienteService(ClienteService clienteService) {
        this.clienteService = clienteService;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public String register() {
        // Calling Business Service
        clienteService.register(cliente);
        // Add message
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("The Employee "+this.cliente.getClienteNome()+" Is Registered Successfully"));
        return "";
    }
}
```

**This is `clienteService.java`:**

```
package spring.service;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import data.Cliente;

@Component
public class ClienteService {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void register(Cliente cliente){
        // Acquire session
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // Save employee, saving behavior get done in a transactional manner
        session.save(cliente);
    }
}
```

**and this is a simple form by `primeface`:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <script name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"></script>
    <title>Register Employee</title>
</h:head>
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="messages"></p:growl>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel value="Enter Employee Name:"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText value="#{registerCliente.cliente.clienteNome}"></p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel value="Enter Employee cognome:"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText value="#{registerCliente.cliente.clienteCognome}"></p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel value="Enter Employee Telefono"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText value="#{registerCliente.cliente.clienteTelefono}"></p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel value="Enter Employee Mail"></p:outputLabel>
         <p:inputText value="#{registerCliente.cliente.clienteMail}"></p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel value="Enter Employee Commessa"></p:outputLabel>
         <p:inputText value="#{registerCliente.cliente.clienteCommessa}"></p:inputText>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Register" action="#{registerCliente.register}" update="messages"></p:commandButton>
</h:form>
</html>
```

**The error is:**

```
ERROR: ERROR: the relation "clienti" not exist
  Position: 13
mar 19, 2015 4:29:53 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
AVVERTENZA: #{registerCliente.register}: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
javax.faces.FacesException: #{registerCliente.register}: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3556)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
    at spring.service.ClienteService.register(ClienteService.java:28)
    at spring.service.ClienteService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a5b2d0d5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:710)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:643)
    at spring.service.ClienteService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d4d2685b.register(<generated>)
    at beans.RegisterCliente.register(RegisterCliente.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:272)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRORE: la relazione "clienti" non esiste
  Posizione: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 61 more

mar 19, 2015 4:29:54 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
GRAVE: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3556)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
    at spring.service.ClienteService.register(ClienteService.java:28)
    at spring.service.ClienteService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a5b2d0d5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:710)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:643)
    at spring.service.ClienteService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d4d2685b.register(<generated>)
    at beans.RegisterCliente.register(RegisterCliente.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:272)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRORE: la relazione "clienti" non esiste
  Posizione: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 61 more
```

i think Spring context don't find the schema "monitoraggio", but see only the general database "misure", and it can't find the request table "clienti"

Can you tell me if is possibile to insert in the database-url the schema? i've tryed with misure?defaultschema=monitoraggio but doesn't work.

Thanks a lot for the answer

***EDIT:***

If I use hibernate.cfg.xml for connecting my database, the code begin:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Misure</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">monitoraggio</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Fabio1990</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <mapping resource="Cliente.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration> -->
```

and with the string

```
`<property name="hibernate.default_schema">monitoraggio</property>`
```

provide me to see the correct schema and the correct table, but I want do it with spring and the beans dataSource in the `applicationcontext.xml` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately the dialog to hibernate for postgres is not the top.
To solve the problems of mapping you have to have is setup like this:
suppose we use spring4 + hibernate4:
in servlet-context.xml you must have the following configuration:
dataSource:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourDb" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

sessionFactory:
<bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">        
                <value>org.youre.package.dto</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Java code mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nametable")
public class NameObjectimplements Serializable{
    private UUID  id;
    private String firstName;
    .
        .
        . 
     //   etc...



    public NameObject() {

    }


    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
**@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")**
    public UUID  getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @Column(name = "`firstName`")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }



//   setter method....
```

the important backquotes !!!! Because unfortunately it is case sensitive !!!!

Do DAO, the Service and for inserting the Controller must set your UUID as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "obj/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertObject(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        NameObject obj= new NameObject();
        obj.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        objService.saveUser(obj);  //@Autowried
        return "obj/saveok";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in postgres  concept is different here is concept of Database &schema one Database have lot of schema & hibernate take public schema by default & you are connecting it with  Database not with schema
you  can do one thing i am giving you option
1.decelare schema at   Dao level
2 at Entity level hibernate have  keyword schema at the time of entity intalization

Comment: so if i chose the second option my hibernate file become: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> <hibernate-configuration> <session-factory> <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property> <property key="hibernate.default_schema">monitoraggio</property> </session-factory> </hibernate-configuration> ?

if i'm in error please can you take me a simple example? thanks a lot

Comment: could you please format your answer at least with newlines? (:

Answer (score 0):

@Entity
@Table(name="demotable" ,schema="demo")

public class DemoEntity{
}

please see I think it will help you I mean to say you are making hbm.xml file But  make Entity in java  is good

**I also edit you hbm file see
use it may be it work for you**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="data.Cliente" schema="monitoraggio"  table="clienti">
    <id column="id" name="clienteId" type="java.lang.Long">
      <generator class="identity">
        <param name="identity">clienti_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property column="nome" name="clienteNome" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property column="cognome" name="clienteCognome" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property column="telefono" name="clienteTelefono" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property column="mail" name="clienteMail" type="string">            
 </property>
    <property column="permesso" name="clientePermesso" type="string">            
    </property>
    <property column="commessa" name="clienteCommessa" type="string">            
</property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: in which of my files I have to put this code ? i don't know it, can you be more specific?

Comment: If you need  need developer of postgres & spring contact me on navintyagi25@gmail.com

Comment: i understand now, thank you so much you save my thesis project for graduation!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `defaultschema=monitoraggio` parameter for the JDBC driver.

Since the driver version 9.3-1103  you can use `currentSchema=monitoraggio` though.

For a list of all valid connection parameters, please see the manual:
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html#connection-parameters

A more robust solution would be to change the `search_path` of your user to make it permanently point to that schema making unquoted table references work:

```
alter user postgres set search_path = 'monitoraggio,public';
```

Don't forget to commit that if you have turned autocommit off in your SQL client.

---

Unrelated but:

By default `postgres` is the superuser for the database. It is usually not a good idea to use that for your regular work (it's like working as `root` in Linux all the time). You should create a regular user to manage your application tables.

Comment: the first solution (currentSchema=monitoraggio) don't work, and with the secont return the same error

Comment: @FabioTramontana: are you using the latest JDBC driver? And if the `set search_path` didn't work, then you are not telling us everything or you set the wrong path, because that **will** work if done correctly.